# Add new factor across multiple groups

Tags: r, dataset, data-cleaning, data

I am trying to add multiple new rows for 3 new factor level in an existing data frame. Please refer to sample data for an example. My starting data frame has 18 levels for `col1` and all 12 months for column `mon` and past 20 years for `year`. I then impute values and add new columns, however I need new factors to be added for further analysis.

For each `mon` and `year` combination, a new level should exist.

**Sample df:**

```
col1 <- c(rep("a",4),rep("b",4)) 
col2 <- c(1:4)  
mon <- c(rep(c("Jan","Feb", "Mar","Apr"), 4))  
year <- c(rep("2016",8), rep("2015",8))  
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(col1,col2,mon,year))
```

**head(df,8)**  # edited to make it readable

```
  col1 col2   mon year  
1 a    1      Jan 2016  
2 a    2      Feb 2016  
3 a    3      Mar 2016  
4 a    4      Apr 2016  
5 b    1      Jan 2016  
6 b    2      Feb 2016  
7 b    3      Mar 2016  
8 b    4      Apr 2016
```

**Expected Output**

```
   col1 col2   mon year  
1  a    1      Jan 2016  
2  a    2      Feb 2016  
3  a    3      Mar 2016  
4  a    4      Apr 2016  
5  b    1      Jan 2016  
6  b    2      Feb 2016  
7  b    3      Mar 2016  
8  b    4      Apr 2016
9  c    NA     Jan 2016  # New level c for each mon and year
10 c    NA     Feb 2016  # New level c for each mon and year
11 c    NA     Mar 2016  # New level c for each mon and year
12 c    NA     Apr 2016  # New level c for each mon and year
```

How do I go about reaching the expected df?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several possibilities. For example, to add `c` for existing `mon`-`year` combinations in your data frame:

```
rbind(df, transform(df[!duplicated(df[, 3:4]), ], col1="c", col2=NA))
#     col1 col2 mon year
# 1      a    1 Jan 2016
# 2      a    2 Feb 2016
# 3      a    3 Mar 2016
# 4      a    4 Apr 2016
# 5      b    1 Jan 2016
# 6      b    2 Feb 2016
# 7      b    3 Mar 2016
# 8      b    4 Apr 2016
# 9      a    1 Jan 2015
# 10     a    2 Feb 2015
# 11     a    3 Mar 2015
# 12     a    4 Apr 2015
# 13     b    1 Jan 2015
# 14     b    2 Feb 2015
# 15     b    3 Mar 2015
# 16     b    4 Apr 2015
# 17     c <NA> Jan 2016
# 21     c <NA> Feb 2016
# 31     c <NA> Mar 2016
# 41     c <NA> Apr 2016
# 91     c <NA> Jan 2015
# 101    c <NA> Feb 2015
# 111    c <NA> Mar 2015
# 121    c <NA> Apr 2015
```

To add `c` for all possible combinations of existing `mon` values and existing `year` values:

```
rbind(df, data.frame(col1="c", col2=NA, expand.grid(mon=levels(df$mon), year=levels(df$year))))
```

To add `c` for all possible combinations of all months names and existing `year` values:

```
rbind(df, data.frame(col1="c", col2=NA, expand.grid(mon=month.abb, year=levels(df$year))))
```

and so on.

Comment: This is great. I am going to take your third option as my solution because it works better for my actual data set. There could be a situation that a month is missing for a year however I would still need the `c` in that case.